# Setting up a cronjob as a file

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I want to create a cronjob at my Ubuntu server by adding/modifying a file in the `/etc/cron.d` folder, rather than using `crontab -e` as it's not too easy to automate.

I've managed to make a file looking like this:

```
* * * * * username command >> logfile
```

I can tell that the file is there, I've chmoded it to `777` but it still isn't executed or appears when I do `crontab -l` as root. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Forget about `crontab -e` and use `crontab my_private_crontab_file` or `crontab -`.

Comment: It won't appear on root's `crontab -l`. Please chmod the file to 0600 and chown it to root.root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file needs to be owned and writeable by root. Also make sure that your time-specification is correct - is `* * * * *` the real one?